# telnet to running zookeeper container

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper

I am running zookeeper as a container and use [zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper/) as image.

```
dockerizer@docker1:~$ docker run --name some-zookeeper --restart always -d zookeeper
3a06702276a4a0cb80fb80d66c380918e12901e1a03106b93a4e1f01d1280fd4

dockerizer@docker1:~$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
3a06702276a4        zookeeper           "/docker-entrypoin..."   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp   some-zookeeper
```

As you can see, the container is running with 3 exposed ports.
The container has following IP address:

```
"Containers": {
            "3a06702276a4a0cb80fb80d66c380918e12901e1a03106b93a4e1f01d1280fd4": {
                "Name": "some-zookeeper",
                "EndpointID": "ff7eeccb2d31e7aeb8c0784fcd972822f74fadaac4bb6e17177685a9bddbe0f1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

Then I try to telnet it as follow:

```
dockerizer@docker1:~$ telnet 172.17.0.2 2181
Trying 172.17.0.2...
Connected to 172.17.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

As you can, there is no response from zookeeper container. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with no response? with telnet you are able to connec to zookeeper on 2181 port.

Comment: Ok, as you can see, I am unable to connect zookeeper through port 2181. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I dont see any problems with connection - you are `Connected to 172.17.0.2.` via `telnet` as it says . Are you able to connect to zookeeper with some zookeeper client?

Comment: It works. In telnet I forget to write `srvr` to check server. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper exposes the functionality of Four Letter Words at the client port (in you case 2181). So you should issue one of the four letter words with telnet. For more information on available Four Letter Words, check the relevant [section](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_4lw) from the Administrator's guide.